# WSO2 BAM REST-API Sample Execution

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I have WSO2BAM V2.2.0 installed on Windows 7 and Cygwin 1.7.18. When I try to run REST-API sample I get the following error in the BAM console.
Can anyone please let me know what can be wrong and how to resolve the issue?

```
TID: [0] [BAM] [2011-05-14 20:46:05,603]  INFO {org.apache.cassandra.service.GCInspector} -  GC for MarkSweepCompact: 408 ms for 1 collections, 94079960 used; max is 1037959168 {org.apache.cassandra.service.GCInspector}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2011-05-14 20:46:05,808] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl} -  Error during query execution.. {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl}
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask.execute(HiveScriptExecutorTask.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:56)    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.jdo.spi.JDOImplHelper.checkAuthorizedStateManager(JDOImplHelper.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MDatabase.jdoReplaceStateManager(MDatabase.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager$1.run(AbstractStateManager.java:298)    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replaceStateManager(AbstractStateManager.java:294)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.updateLevel2CacheForFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:1264)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.loadUnloadedFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:1374)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.state.Hollow.transitionRetrieve(Hollow.java:168)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.retrieve(AbstractStateManager.java:751)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.retrieveObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1472)
    at org.datanucleus.MultithreadedObjectManager.retrieveObject(MultithreadedObjectManager.java:280)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoRetrieve(JDOPersistenceManager.java:621)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.retrieve(JDOPersistenceManager.java:638)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.retrieve(JDOPersistenceManager.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getMDatabase(ObjectStore.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getDatabase(ObjectStore.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveContext.getCurrentContext(HiveContext.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:234)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:217)
    ... 5 more
TID: [0] [BAM] [2011-05-14 20:46:05,813] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Error while executing script : jmx_toolbox_823 {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.exception.HiveExecutionException: Error during query execution..
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:97)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask.execute(HiveScriptExecutorTask.java:60)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:56)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:91)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.jdo.spi.JDOImplHelper.checkAuthorizedStateManager(JDOImplHelper.java:609)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MDatabase.jdoReplaceStateManager(MDatabase.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager$1.run(AbstractStateManager.java:298)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replaceStateManager(AbstractStateManager.java:294)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.updateLevel2CacheForFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:1264)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.loadUnloadedFields(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:1374)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.state.Hollow.transitionRetrieve(Hollow.java:168)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.retrieve(AbstractStateManager.java:751)    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.retrieveObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1472)
    at org.datanucleus.MultithreadedObjectManager.retrieveObject(MultithreadedObjectManager.java:280)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoRetrieve(JDOPersistenceManager.java:621)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.retrieve(JDOPersistenceManager.java:638)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.retrieve(JDOPersistenceManager.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getMDatabase(ObjectStore.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getDatabase(ObjectStore.java:414)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveContext.getCurrentContext(HiveContext.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:234)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:217)
    ... 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but see whether your Java version is JDK 1.7. If so please change to JDK 1.6.

Comment: Thanks. It is 1.6. We had some issues with 1.7 earlier when we started. I suspect it might be Cygwin.

Comment: I have 4 toolboxes installed.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should not be due to Cygwin issue or when publishing data to BAM via rest API. It seems this issue has come when running several hive scripts parallely. How many toolboxes have you installed when you get this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to configure in linux ,it may work.